# Write code for execution time on C# Command Line Application

Tags: c#, console-application, execution-time

I want to have my program execute a bunch of commands on load-time and this is in C# btw, but it's a console program, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific here?  It sounds like you are trying to execute external commands from within your program, is that true?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more. `I want to have my program execute a bunch of commands` is quite confusing. The title and the tags are not helping either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to execute external applications from within your C# console application, see the [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) and [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

Example:

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.google.com");

// -- OR --
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
startInfo.Arguments = "www.google.com";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```